# In a QMenu, how to make a submenu callable like a QAction

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmenu

I am trying to implement something like a classification tree, in which I right-click a row in QTableWidget to call a Menu, then I choose a class label for it. My label tree is like this:

- Class A

  - Class A1
  - Class A2

    - Class A3
- Class B

Here Class A, Class A2 are obviously added through QMenu.addMenu() method, in which they are not callable. Class A1, Class A3, and Class B are added through QMenu.addAction() method and they are callable. So I am wondering is there any way to make a submenu callable like a QAction that can be triggered? Or are there any better ways to achieve my design purpose?

btw I think aboutToShow() signal does not work, since the signal is emitted when the submenu shows up instead of being clicked.

Code:

```py
class ClassMenu(QMenu):

    def __init__(self):
        
        super(ClassMenu, self).__init__()
        class_A = self.addMenu("ClassA")
        class_A1 = class_A.addAction("ClassA1")
        class_A2 = class_A.addMenu("ClassA2")
        class_A3 = class_A2.addAction("ClassA3")
        class_B = self.addAction("ClassB")
        
        class_A1.triggered.connect(self.onMenuClicked)
        class_A3.triggered.connect(self.onMenuClicked)
        class_B.triggered.connect(self.onMenuClicked)

    def onMenuClicked(self):
        print(self.sender().text())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to override mousePressEvent and verify that the QAction associated with the position has a QMenu associated with it:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMenu


class ClassMenu(QMenu):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassMenu, self).__init__()
        class_A = self.addMenu("ClassA")
        class_A1 = class_A.addAction("ClassA1")
        class_A2 = class_A.addMenu("ClassA2")
        class_A3 = class_A2.addAction("ClassA3")
        class_B = self.addAction("ClassB")

        class_A1.triggered.connect(self.onActionClicked)
        class_A3.triggered.connect(self.onActionClicked)
        class_B.triggered.connect(self.onActionClicked)

        print(class_A.menuAction())

    def onActionClicked(self):
        print(self.sender().text())

    def onMenuClicked(self, menu):
        print(menu.title())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        action = self.actionAt(event.pos())
        if not action:
            return
        menu = action.menu()
        if menu:
            self.onMenuClicked(menu)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    menu = ClassMenu()
    menu.move(100, 100)
    menu.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc, I later realized that when class A1 is clicked, I will only receive the signal from class A. I think this is because the actual interface of class A1 (QAction) is in the interface of class A (ClicableMenu), thus the ClicableMenu.clicked will be emitted before QAction.triggered is emitted, is there any solution to this?

Comment: update: I solved this by adding pos = event.pos() and self.actionAt(pos) into mousePressEvent of ClicableMenu